# Matching Value in a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I was playing around with this code for over an hour today and finally got it to work.  Can someone please explain why I have to declare my shopOrder variable as a long before this code will work?  What type of variable is shopOrder if I omit the "Dim shopOrder as Long" line?

```
Dim shopOrder As Long
Dim lastUsedRow As Long

lastUsedRow = wsjobs.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
shopOrder = 15150664

If Not IsError(Application.Match(shopOrder, Range("E1:E" & lastUsedRow), 0)) Then
    MsgBox ("This shop order already exists!")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: `What type of variable is shopOrder if I omit the "Dim shopOrder as Long" line` - type would be `Variant/Long`. See screen: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qCveg.png . Code should work for both cases with `Dim shopOrder As Long` and when declaration is ommited (unless you're using `Option Explicit`). The problem may be with `Range("E1:E" & lastUsedRow)` - it always searching in _active_ sheet. Use `wsjobs.Range("E1:E" & lastUsedRow)` for reliability

Comment: Always declare your variables :)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the VBA data type, you will see that ***long*** are 4 bytes long and cover range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Probably your variable had the type ***int*** wich are 2 bytes long and cover only -32,768 to 32,767.

The value you've assigned to it was greater than 32,767.